# May the total charge in a supercapacitor be different using unipolar and bipolar voltage power supply?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, capacitance

Consider a supercapacitor where a Helmoltz double layer is formed at each of the 2 electrodes, which is like having 2 capacitors mounted in series, but with different polarities.

The total charge at the electrodes will depend not only on the capacitance of the electrodes, but also on the concentration of the electrolyte (with positive and negatively charged ions).

Does applying the same voltage difference between electrodes (e.g. 1 V), may lead to different total accumulated charges at the double layers (both electrodes), caused by the fact that I'm using a unipolar (**0, 1 V**) or bipolar (**-0.5, +0.5**)? I know that the capacitance is the same, no matter the voltage, but would the positively charged ions tend to form the double layer at the electrode that is connected to 0 V?

I think that it would not make a difference if the source it's uni or bipolar for a supercapacitor with a constant electrolyte, because no matter the polarity, all the ions will feel the electric field and will accumulate at the lowest potential regarding themselves.

But now consider "Capacitive Deionization". This is a technique for water demineralization that consists basically in a supercapacitor but with one difference - the electrolyte is the water that is **flowing between** the electrodes. This means that if everything outside the supercapacitor is connected to ground, the potential difference between the electrode at 0V and the outside, is zero.

So, for this case of capacitive deionization where the electrolyte is not constant, will the positively charged ions form a double layer?

Comment: The capacitor does not know "where" the ground potential of your power supply is, so the answer is negative. It does not make any difference.

Comment: @CuriousOne But if the potential on one electrode of the capacitors is zero volts, does not that make the difference between that electrode and the outside of the capacitor (connected to ground) equal to zero? If that's so, then I would say the positively charged ions would be equally distributed along an area much larger than the electrode's, so the charge density would be almost zero.

Comment: Potentials are only defined up to an additive constant. Whether a capacitor is sitting on "ground" or a million volts above ground makes no difference for what is going on on the inside, for that only the potential difference between the plates matters. The external electric field can not enter from the outside (at least usually not to any measurable extent), so you don't have to care about it.

Comment: @CuriousOne I understand that, but if the electrolyte is in electrical contact with the outside, because it's water flowing through the capacitor, then I would think that in this case that would make a difference.

Comment: I have never seen a capacitor of that type and I wouldn't call it capacitor to begin with. That's an electrochemical cell. Even for that kind of setup the external voltages won't make too much of a mess because the impedance of a tube of electrolyte is a lot higher than the impedance of parallel plates with extremely high surface area. If you are worried about it, you can always measure the currents flowing trough the electrolyte tubes and compensate electronically with an active guard.